# Background image em div diagonal clip-path

Tags: html, css3

Consegui fazer assim com background de cor sólida

```css
.slide {
 width: 100%;
 height: 101px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
}
.slide_bg{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding-bottom:20px;
   padding-left:20px;
  }
.slide_end {
 width: 100%;
 height: 101px;
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
}

.slide_end_bg {
 width: 100%;
 
  background-color:#fff;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="slide_bg">

<p>
asdasdasd
</p>
<p>
asdasdasd
</p>
<p>
asdasdasd
</p>
</div>

<div class="slide_end_bg">
<div class="slide_end">
  
</div>
</div>
```

Como posso colocar uma imagem como background em uma div com o **clip-path** na diagonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara a forma que vc montou seu `html/css` vc não vai conseguir, por vc tem um elemento onde coloca o texto e outro onde coloca o `clip-path`, vc precisa que seja tudo um elemento só com o texto e o `bg` pegando no `clip-path` inteiro.

**Sua estrutura estava dessa forma, mas precisa ser tudo um elemento só...** Não tem como vc fazer o BG passar do elemento verde para o vermelho, vc tem que junta-los em um `clip-path` único
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Segue um exemplo corrigindo isso.***

Vc vai ver que eu dei até uma simplificada no código para poder funcionar. Eu coloquei o `clip-path` no mesmo elemento que vai ter o texto dendro e usei um `background-image` e ficou tudo certo

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.slide_bg {
  padding-top: 0.75em;
  padding-bottom: 6em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-image: url(http://placecage.com/620/380);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 70%, 50% 100%, 0 70%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 70%, 50% 100%, 0 70%, 0 0);
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.slide_bg:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(http://placecage.com/620/383);
}
```

```html
<div class="slide_bg">
    <p>
        asdasdasd
    </p>
    <p>
        asdasdasd
    </p>
    <p>
        asdasdasd
    </p>
</div>

<div class="slide_bg">
    <div>
        asdasdasd
    </div>
    <p>
        asdasdasd
    </p>
    <span>
        asdasdasd
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Quando eu coloco mais de uma div, fica com defeito nas linhas diagonais, como eu poderia fazer com mais de uma div seguindo esse exemplo? http://jsfiddle.net/bn7mfj58/40/

Comment: @WagnerMartinsBodyboard cara eu dei uma editada na pergunta, repara que agora eu coloquei duas divs como o clip-path, inclusive na segunda div eu coloquei dentro outra div, um P e um Span, e fica tudo certo... Acredito que deve ser algum outro CSS que está afetando a sua div. Testa ela em um página em branco para ver o que acontece, ou use o Inspect do DevTools do browser pra tentar ver o que está acontecendo. Qualquer coisa fala ai

Comment: @WagnerMartinsBodyboard acabou que só agora reparei que tinha um link para o JsFiddle, eu dei uma olhada no seu layout, parece que está ok... Não entendi o que vc gostaria de muda?

Comment: sim está certo agora, obrigado :)